# "Exported" functions in cython pyd module

Tags: python, cython

I'm using cython to compile my python script to a .pyd module.
My python script looks like:

```
    class WorkingThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ...
    class Ui_Dialog(object):
    ...
    def Function1():
    ...
    def Function2():
    ...
    def main():
    ...
```

How can I make all classes and functions accessible only inside compiled module?
So basically I want pyd module to "export" only main() function nothing more.

EDIT:
A guy from cython-users gave me the solution:pre-declare class as

```
cdef object MyClass
```

so my code should look like

```
cdef object WorkingThread
cdef object Ui_Dialog
class WorkingThread(QtCore.QThread):
...
class Ui_Dialog(object):
...
cdef Function1():
...
cdef Function2():
...
def main():
...
```

Comment: please, post the given solution as an answer... you can get some upvotes and close this question

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, for your application you probably can't. The way to do this would be to convert your functions and classes to cdef functions and classes, then call them from your main function. But you won't be able to obfuscate everything if you want to be able to derive from normal python classes (such as QThread). Here's an example showing what will be exposed and what won't:

```
def Function1():
    # This function will be exposed
    pass

cdef Function2():
    # But this cdef function will not
    pass

cdef class UI_Dialog: 
    # This class will be exposed

    cdef object storage # This member won't be exposed

    def def_func(self): 
        # This member function will be available
        pass

    cdef cdef_func(self):
        # But this one will not be available
        pass

#cdef class WorkingThread(QTCore.QThread):
    # This wouldn't even compile; cdef classes can't
    # derive from non cdef classes

class WorkingThread(QTCore.QThread):
    # This is a normal python class, and is exposed

    def __init__(self):
        #You're free to call cdef functions in here
        Function2()
        self.dialog = UI_Dialog()

        #But you can't access cdef members,
        #So the following wouldn't compile
        #self.dialog.storage
        #self.dialog.cdef_func()

        # But you can access def members
        self.dialog.def_func()

cdef hidden_main():
    # This function isn't exposed, and you can also call
    # cdef functions in here, and access cdef members
    Function1()
    Function2()
    dialog = UI_Dialog()
    dialog.def_func()
    dialog.cdef_func()
    dialog.storage = dict()
    workingThread = WorkingThread()

def main():
    # Here you can just call your hidden_main
    hidden_main()
```

Basically any logic you want to hide needs to be in cdef functions, you can't hide classes at all, but you can hide the accessibility of members of those classes. If you want to hide a member of a class, it needs to be a cdef class, and those can't derive from Python classes.

It's also important to note that you can't simply make any normal python function into a cdef function (although I think that's the eventual goal). Currently cdef functions don't support closures, and I believe this means they also don't support generators.